# 'System.UriFormatException' for 'WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()' when authorizing SharpBox in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sharpbox

I want to open the web to let user allow my app to access their files. The code is here:

```
    config = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox) as DropBoxConfiguration;
    requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, "XXXXXXXX", "YYYYYYYYY");
    AuthorizationUrl = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(config, requestToken);

    Uri requestUri = new Uri(AuthorizationUrl);
    Debug.WriteLine("Done requestUri");

    Uri callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
    Debug.WriteLine("Done callbackUri");

    WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, callbackUri);
    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
         ICloudStorageAccessToken accessToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.ExchangeDropBoxRequestTokenIntoAccessToken(config, "7nu03leznnz6x74", "ex3gge8av7kp9lq", requestToken);
    }
```

With these instances declared before the constructor():

```
    static DropBoxRequestToken requestToken;
    static DropBoxConfiguration config;
    String AuthorizationUrl;
```

When I run it, I have the exception `A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.ni.dll` at `Uri callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();` line.

And if I change `Uri callbackUri` to a string like
`Uri callbackUri = new Uri("https://google.com");`

it works just fine to`Debug.WriteLine("Done callbackUri");` but new exception occurs:

`An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary` in the line:

`WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri, callbackUri);`

So what did I do wrong? I just want to make the callback call to the app after opening web authorizing.

Thank you.